# Laravel (PHP) and Owl Carousel Issues

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, owl-carousel

[image]

I am trying to create a product image gallery for my Laravel project using Owl Carousel.  The main image, stored in the database under the "image" column, appears just fine in both the primary image and the thumbnail gallery.  The thumbnail gallery, at the moment, is incorrectly repeatedly populated with the image from the "image" column, when it should be populated from both the "image" column and the images located in the "images" column.

I have written HTML/CSS/PHP/etc. attempting to accomplish the aforementioned, but I'm not having any luck (again, I just keep getting a repeat of the image from the "image" column in the thumbnail gallery).  Here is the applicable code:

```
<div class="product-images col-lg-6">
        <div data-slider-id="1" class="owl-carousel items-slider owl-drag">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="{{ productImage($product->image) }}" alt="product" id="currentImage">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div data-slider-id="1" class="owl-thumbs d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
          <button class="owl-thumb-item">
            <img src="{{ productImage($product->image) }}" alt="product">
          </button>

          @if ($product->images)
            @foreach (json_decode($product->images, true) as $image)
              <button class="owl-thumb-item">
                <img src="{{ productImage($product->image) }}" alt="product">
              </button>
            @endforeach
          @endif
        </div>
      </div>
```

The script "I" wrote:

```
<script>
  (function(){
    const currentImage = document.querySelector('#currentImage');
    const images = document.querySelectorAll('.owl-thumb-item');

    images.forEach((element) => element.addEventListener('click', thumbnailClick));

    function thumbnailClick(e) {
      currentImage.src = this.querySelector('img').src;
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Any suggestions as to what I might be doing wrong?  I've tried troubleshooting, different variations, and walking away/coming back, but with no luck.

Comment: Can you post some images of how it is breaking? Also, any error console messages?

Comment: Done.  Also, clicking on the images in the thumbnail gallery does not change the main slider image (although I might not be able to tell the difference because all the images are the same).  Thank you!

Comment: Any ideas?  Somehow both the main image and the thumbnail images are not updating, though the code does recognize that there are a total of 7 images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second productImage function call, you are passing `$product->image` which refers to your primary image. You want to be passing just `$image` like:

`productImage($image)`

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  Now all the thumbnails are correct, but when a thumbnail is clicked, it isn't updating the larger image.  I will see if I can figure it out and come back if I get stuck again.  Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: No worries. Carousels are always pretty painful to get working!

Comment: The issue is now completely resolved.  I had to add an if loop, with a nested foreach loop, to the first slider (not just the thumbnail area).  I also needed to @yield('extra-js') in my layout.blade.php.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Thank you!  Can I ask your opinion on approaches to product variation?  Say, for example, I have a product that can have many flavors, or a product that can have many sizes, or both.  Should I create a table called flavors and a table called sizes, then define a one-to-many relationship or is there a better way to do it?  Thank you!

Comment: It really is a tricky one to answer. If the flavors/sizes have other attributes involved then I would say yes, if not, I would say an enum or similar would suffice